# Given the above Java code fragment, SELECT the statement which identifies the number of APIs available to demonstrate dynamic polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
public class Student extends Person {
    private double gpa;
    public Student(String name, double gpa) {
        super(name);
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }
    public void setGpa(double gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student " + getName() + ", with a GPA of " + gpa;
    }
}
```

Given the above Java code fragment, SELECT the statement which identifies the number of APIs available to demonstrate dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: What is the question? This looks like a homework problem as it is written.

Comment: I saw this question in a quiz. 
The question is "Given the above Java code fragment, SELECT the statement which identifies the number of APIs available to demonstrate dynamic polymorphism."

Options are: A) 1 
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4